# How to add/embed android google map app i had made to another android application

Tags: android, google-maps, embed, integrate

I had made android application for google map. and now i want to add/embed this application to my new android application. Please tell me how to move further on this?
Thanx in advance

Comment: specify more detail .. if you want to integrate you can simply copy package and xml file in respective directory and mention the permission in manifest like wise ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the following steps:

1. Change your project build target of the destination application, Project -> properties -> Android -> Project Build Target and then select the Google APIS one.
2. Copy all the files (java and xml) to the destination application source.
3. Rename the files if they conflict with the existing files.
4. I guess you should know this one, rename the destination activity's parent to MapActivity if you want to use MapViews.
5. Enter in the AndroidManifest.xml:
   uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps">
6. Also enter the required permissions if you wish to use location updates:
   INTERNET, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION